# Debugging a signed APK with Eclipse / adb

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, billing

I need to debug a signed APK (must be signed because of a billing problem). However, it crashes on startup, so I need to get it under control of the debugger before it does anything.

I've found a question / answer about debugging a signed APK, but that requires you to connect to its process with DDMS once it has started - the problem being it has crashed long before I get to doing that.

I need therefore to be able to load and start the signed APK using Eclipse / adb, setting a breakpoint in the main activity onCreate(), so I get control before it does anything.

Can I do that?

Comment: logcat does not provide enough information to pinpoint the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on your needs - but if you're just trying to debug an app that's signed and installed on your phone, why don't you just connect the phone to your computer, launch it, and just read LogCat in Eclipse when it launches to see the error?

Comment: Well, one can always use logcat. However what's going on is a bit involved and a debugger allows one much more flexibility at stepping through code, looking at values etc, without needing to continually make code changes to add new log statements.

Comment: I don't even know how you'd launch a signed debug app from eclipse though. If it's signed, its exported into an APK, that's installed not through eclipse, right?